# Avoid hard coding the mysql container ip in my apache container script

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a `mysql` container which runs fine. I can start it and see it up and running in the docker ps list.

I then try to run another `learnitouch` container in which an `engine-db-seed.sh` shell script tries to connect to the mysql container server.

The `learnitouch` container Dockerfile contains:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/usr/bin/learnintouch/engine-db-seed.sh"]
```

The `engine-db-seed.sh` file contains:

```
/usr/bin/mysql/install/bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h 172.17.0.2 -u root -proot -v < /usr/bin/learnintouch/db_engine-db.sql
```

The `db_engine-db.sql` is being seeded all right in the mysql database.

But I had to hard code the `mysql` container IP as you can see in the `-h` option. I got the `172.17.0.2` IP address from a docker inspect on the `mysql` container. Not the most automated way...

How can I do without such hard coding ?

Running the `mysql` container:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -v /home/stephane/dev/php/learnintouch/docker/mysql/data:/usr/bin/mysql/install/data --name mysql stephane/mysql:5.6.30
```

Running the `learnintouch` container:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 --link mysql:mysql --name learnintouch stephane/learnintouch
```

I'm using Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the service name and make sure that both services are running on the same network (bridge0 by default).

So if you create your mysql service like this

```
docker run -d --name foo mysql-image
```

your `engine-db-seed.sh` could then be

```
/usr/bin/mysql/install/bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h foo -u root -proot -v < /usr/bin/learnintouch/db_engine-db.sql
```

mysql will make a dns request for `foo` which will be resolved by Docker to the ip of your `foo` service.

Comment: I didn't know the container name was offered as the service host name. Thanks !